# Extract data from an HTML table

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I'm learning Nokogiri in the mechanize gem, and I'm having trouble figuring out the right selector to use to build an array from an html table.  Here's the HTML table I need to extract data from:

```html
<table id="propertysearchresults">
  <thead>…</thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="prototype_r">
      <td class="transparent">…</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td> ITEM ONE </td>
      <td> ITEM TWO </td>
      <td class="location">…</td>
      <td> ITEM THREE </td>
      <td class="text_right">ITEM FOUR</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="prototype_r">
      <td class="transparent">…</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td> ITEM ONE </td>
      <td> ITEM TWO </td>
      <td class="location">…</td>
      <td> ITEM THREE </td>
      <td class="text_right">ITEM FOUR</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'd like to build an array for items one through four for each row of data.  If someone could help out with the syntax I'd appreciate it.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that items one/two/three/four are always in the same td indexes, you could do it like this:

```
# Writing standalone; use Mechanize to fetch if you like
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri.HTML( page_html )

data = doc.css('#propertysearchresults > tbody > tr').map do |row|
  row.elements.to_a.values_at(2,3,5,6).map(&:text)
end

p data
#=> [
#=>   [" ITEM ONE ", " ITEM TWO ", " ITEM THREE ", "ITEM FOUR"],
#=>   [" ITEM ONE ", " ITEM TWO ", " ITEM THREE ", "ITEM FOUR"]
#=> ]
```

This uses a CSS expression to select the rows, and for each it finds the child elements (the `<td>`) as an array, extracts the correct ones by index, and then gets the `text` for each.

Comment: that's a lot less code than I thought it would take.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This episode of Railscasts really helped me for such things because they showed a tool called SelectorGadget which made it really easy to figure out what css selectors to use to identify the targeted information.

[Railscasts #190: Screen scraping with Nokogiri](http://railscasts.com/episodes/190-screen-scraping-with-nokogiri)